# Can we use multiple hive server in JDBC URL for failover

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is it possible to use multiple `hive` servers in the `jdbc` URL?

```
jdbc:hive2://ip1:10000,ip2:10000/;transportMode=http;
```

Basically I want an Active Passive kind of setup and if the first server is not available i want to use the second one. I don't want to go through zk setup as load balancing is not required.

I am using hive over socks proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zookeeper is for failover also, not just load balancing, and that's how you can get a highly available HiveServer connection

> To provide high availability **or** load balancing for HiveServer2, Hive provides a function called dynamic service discovery where multiple HiveServer2 instances can register themselves with Zookeeper

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSCRJT_5.0.1/com.ibm.swg.im.bigsql.admin.doc/doc/admin_HA_HiveS2.html

You should be using Zookeeper already for a highly available namenode

Comment: Well we are using hive from a public internet over socks proxy. Zookeeper since it uses nio doesnt support socks. Our requirement is for failover and if the HiveConnection class implement such a policy of multiple HiveServer then it is good enough for us.

Comment: It doesn't... The best you'll get is some external TCP load balancer pointing at the JDBC endpoint